# Not able to execute a url from python script running on aws ec2 via Cron

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a script web.py which I am trying to run on the aws EC2 Instance using cron. It basically has these line of codes:

```
      import webbrowser 
      webbrowser.open('http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

If I run this script through command line using "python web.py" it does hit the browser. But same is not working if I run it via cron. My cron code is :

```
     */10 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/web.py
```

The way I know its not working is there are few process which get executed once the url is hit. I can see those changes when I run the script through putty but not when I run it through cron.

I tried below modifications also but its not working.

```
  */10 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/python /home/web.py
  */10 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python /home/web.py
```

Also, on echo $DISPLAY, I get a null result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does your script use environment variables? Cron sees a different environment and this is a common problem.

Comment: When it tries to run but fails, do you get any error messages?

Comment: I am not sure I understood you. I think I am not using any environment variables in the script. Is there a way to make them see a common environment?

Comment: At a minimum you're using `PYTHONPATH`.  Perhaps this variable has a different value when executed via cron?